# Missing typescript compiled javascript file of an referenced library in my output folder when publishing via console command

Tags: javascript, .net, typescript, publishing, blazor-webassembly

We have an blazor-webassembly project and an referenced blazor-library (BlazorLib):

[image]

The client project references the BlazorLib:

[image]

There is an Javascript file called `blazorLib.js` which is compiled by typescript´s file `blazorLib.ts`:

[image]

**The Target:**

We want do publish the solution via the following command line:

```
dotnet build "Performancelog\Server\PerformanceLog.Server.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="NewRelease"
```

**The Problem:**

When the command is completed, then in the output-folder, the `src`-folder and containing file `blazorLib.js` are missing:

[image]

**Question:**

How can we include the file `src/blazorLib.js` into the published output folder?

**Here are some further information:**

The **file properties** of the `blazorLib.js` file:

[image]

The `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*"
  ]
}
```

The **publish profile**:

[image]

We tried it with `dotnet publish` and also the src/blazorLib.js file is missing:

```
dotnet publish $PathToProject --configuration Release -f net5.0 -o "$PathToOutput" --self-contained true --runtime win-x64
```

When we use the publish-function in Visual Studio, then the file `src/blazorLib.js` existst in the output folder. That is curious. But we want to use the command line.

Comment: blazorLib.js is changed to blazorLib.min.js as it is minified and recompiled. check that.

Comment: Check your setting for Debug and Release configuration and make sure csproj doesn't have any conditions attached to the missing files (hint: unload project and edit .csproj)